# Как узнать полный путь к html элементу?

Tags: javascript, dom

У меня есть функция, которая вызывается при нажатии на какой-либо элемент. И внутри этой функции я могу обращаться к нему. Но как узнать весь "путь" или не знаю как точно сказать, к элементу, чтобы я мог из других функций обращаться к нему?

Comment: Добавьте своему элементу атрибут `id`, например `<div id="div-123">` и  ... `var element = document.getElementById("div-123")`

Answer (score 1):

Зачем? Передавайте этот элемент в качестве аргумента в другие функции